# Why will my replace method in my elif statement not replace the letter or letters I am trying to replace in my program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
myWord=input("Enter a Word: ")

if len(myWord) <= 3 :
    print(myWord)
elif myWord[-3:] == 'ing':
    print(myWord)
elif myWord[-1:] == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
    newWord = myWord.replace('a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u', "ing")
    print(newWord)
```

I am working on a program that whenever I put input a word that is < than 3 words and ends with a vowel it will replace that vowel with "ing". The third "elif" statement is where I am having the most problems because whenever I run the program and type in a word that ends with a vowel it does not replace the vowel with "ing".

Comment: In addition `myWord.replace('a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u', "ing")` is used incorrectly.

Comment: I apologize... I am fairly new to python, so what would you suggest I use instead? Am I using the "or" method incorrectly?

Comment: replace function works with single characters, so you have to loop across all the vowels. `for v in ['a','e','i','o','u']: myWord.replace(v, 'ing')`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow, `myWord[-1:] == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':` does not what you thing it does, I'm afraid, it does not compare myword[-1] to those five things but does the comparision and then does `if 'a'` which is always true. Try

```
if myWord[-1:] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
```

Also in the last elif you should not use replace (and here also the or-structure is not correct), because it replaces all occurences of, not only the last one.

Comment: if `myWord[-1] in` ...  then what?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, I was just providing a corrected version of `elif myWord[-1:] == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':`

Comment: Yeah.  But that does answer the question..   If you are going to just give hints, that is what comments are for.